# Find all substring from another column - ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access, substring, ms-access-2016

**tblCode** is a dummy table from which I want to pull records. Row-wise each `code` values (example 32) should be checked in `subcode` and should return all records if found in any part of string.

```
+----+------+----------+
| ID | code |  subCode |
+----+------+----------+
| 1  |      | 234322   |
+----+------+----------+
| 5  | 32   | 8999999  |
+----+------+----------+
| 2  |      | 32       |
+----+------+----------+
| 7  |      | 45       |
+----+------+----------+
| 6  |      | 56565465 |
+----+------+----------+
| 3  | 45   | 6767676  |
+----+------+----------+
| 4  |      | 7894522  |
+----+------+----------+
| 8  |      | 83       |
+----+------+----------+
```

For instance, when I run following query, I get 2 records

```
`SELECT * from tblCode where subCode like '*45*'`
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcNkP.png)

The actual table is huge with several `code` & `subCode`.
I have tried following query but returns incorrect results

```
`SELECT * from tblCode where subCode like '*'& code &'*'`
```

Answer (score 1):

A *Cartesian* (multiplying) query will do:

```sql
SELECT 
    tblCode.ID, 
    tblCode_1.code, 
    tblCode.subCode
FROM 
    tblCode, 
    tblCode AS tblCode_1
WHERE 
    tblCode_1.code Is Not Null AND 
    tblCode.subCode Like "*" & [tblCode_1]![code] & "*";
```

Output:

[image]